# How can you make <html> show inside of a <p> tag?

Tags: html

I am currently creating a webpage to teach others HTML.  In my HTML document, I want to make a paragraph like, "Start with html, and end with /html". The html and /html should have <> tags around them, but I don't know how to do this! (this is my question) The document just leaves html and /html (with <> around them) out.  How do I make sure that the document leaves it in?

Thank you.

Comment: If you must ask that question, maybe you shouldn't be teaching HTML just yet.

Comment: I'm not realeasing it, just making it to help me understand HTML better.

Comment: I don't see the harm in this. On the contrary, I encourage you to do so. You will learn a lot. And, later-on you may even want to release it! That could help others. Make a beautiful HTML learning resource! :)

Comment: Sure, trying to explain to others is the best way to learn, actually. As somewhat more constructive comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use HTML entities

To write the characters **<** and **>** use `&lt;` and `&gt;`
**This gives you:**

```
&lt;html&gt; and &lt;/html&gt;
```

Rendered as:
<html> and </html>

This is called [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). A more complete list can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) or on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

> In HTML, there is a standard set of 252 named character entities for
>   characters - some common, some obscure - that are either not found in
>   certain character encodings or are markup sensitive in some contexts
>   (for example angle brackets and quotation marks). Although any Unicode
>   character can be referenced by its numeric code point, some HTML
>   document authors prefer to use these named entities instead, where
>   possible, as they are less cryptic and were better supported by early
>   browsers. Character entities can be included in an HTML document via
>   the use of entity references, which take the form &EntityName;, where
>   EntityName is the name of the entity. For example, `&mdash;`, much like
>   `&#8212;` or `&#x2014;`, represents U+2014: the em dash character "—" even
>   if the character encoding used doesn't contain that character.

Comment: Yes. We need to put them between " ` " so that they don't get interpreted on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Use amp codes ([HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))!

```
<p>&lt;html&gt;</p>
```

Comment: I see no reason to downvote your post. May my upvote compensate for this and give you happiness.

Comment: lol I edited out that comment; just silly about downvoting a correct answer. I guess the other guy got his accept, which is all that matters, right?

Comment: @IsaMeg In my (small) experience here, the easiest questions are those who attract the largest number of answers, and the only ones where you  can get downvotes out of thin air… Zipp: +1 for saying it out loud.

Answer (score 2):

use &lt for < and &gtfor >

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML entities: `&gt;` for >, `&lt;` for <.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display HTML tags replace all < and > with `&lt;` and `&lt;`

Example: `&lt;HTML&gt;`